# How to get response from GET-request to API in okhttp?

Tags: java, get, request, okhttp

How can i get some response from API through GET-request?

**The way i'm sending GET:**

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    client.setConnectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);//Connect timeout
    client.setReadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);//Socket timeout

    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(String.valueOf(message)).build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

**The way i'm trying to get response:**

```
response.message();
```

**What i get:**

```
OK
```

**What i need to get from API:**

```
OK|ID (Example: OK|2122988149)
```

Comment: What is 2122988149?

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
response.body().string()
```